# If $\sqrt{1-a}\leq\sqrt{1-b}+\sqrt{1-c}$ would it imply $\sqrt{1-a^2}\leq\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1-c^2}$?

Tags: inequality

Question: If $\sqrt{1-a}\leq\sqrt{1-b}+\sqrt{1-c}$ would it imply $\sqrt{1-a^2}\leq\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1-c^2}$

That is, $a,b,c\in [-1,1].$

Would this inequality necessarily be true?

I tried to break up $\sqrt{1-a^2}=\sqrt{1-a}\sqrt{1+a}\leq\sqrt{1+a}(\sqrt{1-b}+\sqrt{1-c}).$ However I am not sure how to proceed further. I also cannot seem to find a counter example either.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  An easy counterexample: let $c=-1, a=0$, then $$1=\sqrt{1-a}<\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{1-c}\leq\sqrt{1-b}+\sqrt{1-c},$$
but you won't have $1=\sqrt{1-a^2}\leq\sqrt{1-b^2}=\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1-c^2}$ unless $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=0$ and $b=-1,$ then $ \sqrt{1-a}\leq\sqrt{1-b}+\sqrt{1-c}$ holds for $c \in [-1,1].$

But $\sqrt{1-a^2}\leq\sqrt{1-b^2}+\sqrt{1-c^2}$ does not hold.